# CORS problem requesting a file (ONLY on Google Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, .net-core, cors, babylonjs, referrer-policy

I have a .Net Core API and a React application using BabylonJs to render some 3D models. On my server side I am storing the 3D models that will be requested by the client to render into the scene. In order to do so I have allowed `UseFileServer` and `UseStaticFiles` on my .Net Core server. I have also created a Policy to apply for requests that require the CORS policy. The policy that I implemented is the following:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policyBuilder => policyBuilder
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                    .AllowCredentials());
        });
```

And I am applying it to the requests that target the Static files the following way:

```
app.UseFileServer(enableDirectoryBrowsing: true);
app.UseStaticFiles(fileOptions);
```

On the client side the request is being done by the Babylon library the following way:

```
SceneLoader.ImportMeshAsync(
      "",
      "http://localhost:9001/resources/objects/",
      "sphere.glb",
      scene
    )
      .then((result) => {
        result.renderingGroupId = 1;
        scene.createDefaultCamera(true, true, true);
        scene.activeCamera.alpha += Math.PI;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return null;
      });
```

What happens is that I am receiving the following error only on google chrome and **not** on Firefox neither on Opera.

[image]

Also the responses to Firefox and Opera contain the *missing header* while the response to chrome does not.

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

Opera:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research time I found the solution for my problem. What was causing the issue was not CORS. It looks like Google has made a security upgrade to Chrome that has changed the Referrer-Policy to:

[image]

wgile both other browsers remain on:

[image]
[image]

As so, google only support CORS on https->https sites. After creating a self-signed certificate and open a port for https problem was resolved.